# Setting ESP8266-01 up with AT commands

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I am facing for the first time with the ESP8266-01 module, so sorry if will write any stupid things.

I bought [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13678) module and I wanted to check its parameters through AT commands. Following some guide and wiring schemas found on the web I finally hook the ESP8266 up with an Arduino Uno (as in the picture below. The resistors are 220ohm each and the capacitor is 100uF) in order to print out to the serial monitor the AT commands and responses.

I uploaded the following code to Arduino Uno:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial esp8266(6, 7);

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  Serial.println("Started");

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  esp8266.begin(57600);
  esp8266.write("AT\r\n");
}

void loop() {
  if (esp8266.available()) {
    Serial.write(esp8266.read());
  }

  if (Serial.available()) {
    esp8266.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

But when I open the serial monitor (with both NL and CR selected and baud rate set to 9600) **I got no response**!!
If I try to send simple AT or AT+GMR commands, it returns to me nothing or random characters.

Does anyone please could tell me what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Try different common esp8266 baud rates. Different versions use different baud rates.

Comment: Also I know for a fact I have answered this very same question twice this month already.

Comment: This question is over a year old - have you solved your issue yet?

Comment: @Filipppo, please don’t just edit your title to say “solved”. That’s not helpful to anyone. If you solved it, please post the solution as an answer.

Comment: For future readers of this question, see my answer to a similar question, about [Software Serial, ESP8266 modules and baud rate](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/36447/wifiesp-not-working-on-software-serial-working-fine-on-hardware-serial/36453#36453).

Answer (score 1):

We faced similar problems when using ESP8266 for the first time, Following approach to the problem was fruitful

1. ESP8266 is 3.3v compatible so to avoid problems make a simple adaptor circuit to make it compatible with 5v Arduino ([find details here](http://absaransari.com/2018/01/25/how-to-power-esp8266-from-5v-supply/))
2. First thing you need to do is check and confirm if you are able to communicate with your ESP module, you can use any USB to TTL interface and connect ESP Module directly with your computer/laptop. ([explained in detail here](http://absaransari.com/2018/01/26/connecting-esp8266-wifi-mobile-with-computer-using-pl2303/))
3. Use ESP8266 configuration utility, it will speed up the ESP Module setup and help get the desired product develop faster. ([explained in detail here](http://absaransari.com/2018/01/27/esp8266-wifi-module-configuration-utility/))

Hope it helps.